# Cannot access phpmyadmin account using '%' as host

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, host, account

I cannot access phpmyadmin account with host %. I tried accessing it from another IP but still I cannot log in. I want to put up a remote database server.

Comment: Maybe the port is closed by the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a web server (1) with a PHP script that needs to connect to a MySQL database on a remote host (2)?  Or does phpMyAdmin show you any error message while trying to log in?

For login, phpMyAdmin uses the MySQL permissions.  So, when in doubt, double-check that the MySQL user rights are set correctly.

### Update

#### Editing user rights from shell

Provided that you have shell access, try to connect from the host that the database server is running on, like this:

```
user@databasehost:~$  mysql -uUSERNAME -p
```

After logging in, you may check the user rights with the `mysql.user` table, like

```sql
USE `mysql`;
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user` = 'USERNAME';
```

Then, update your password like this:

```
UPDATE `user` SET `password` = PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE `user` = 'USERNAME';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Yes, that is my set up. when I log in from my local machine to phpmyadmin with host '%', I cannot login and it says #1045 Cannot login to the MySQL server. Same with if I access it using a different IP address. How can I configure user rights?